# importing models inside django application

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have made an app inside my django application. I'm trying to create a file(testabc.py) in the same directory as views.py and I want to import models in that file.

The name of model is "Example"

Now, in views.py, I import models in the following way:

**from .models import Example**

**a = Example.objects.get()**

Here, I am getting proper output

However, in my testabc.py file when I write the same code
I get the following error

**from .models import Example**

**ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package**

Comment: Generally, relative imports are not a good idea. Use `from myapp.models import Example` everywhere and there will be no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add file **__init__.py** in your folder.
Here is the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for python module.